# T-SQL function does not return all values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-function

I have 2 tables, `contact` and `membership`

Here is the data from my tables:

**CONTACT:**

```
SERIALNUMBER    TITLE   FIRSTNAME   SURNAME
     1           Mr       John        Doe
     2           Mrs      Jane        Doe
```

**MEMBERSHIP:**

```
MEMBERSHIPID    NAME    SERIALNUMBER
     1          TEST        1
     1          TEST        2
```

When I write the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CONTACT C
INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIP M
ON C.SERIALNUMBER=M.SERIALNUMBER
WHERE M.MEMBERSHIPID = '1'
```

I see the following results:

```
SERIALNUMBER    TITLE   FIRSTNAME   SURNAME MEMBERSHIPID    NAME    SERIALNUMBER
     1           Mr      John        Doe         1          TEST        1
     2           Mrs     Jane        Doe         1          TEST        2
```

Then I have written the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetMemberNames] (@MEMBERSHIPID VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @name_to_return AS VARCHAR(50);
  SET @name_to_return = NULL;
  SELECT  @name_to_return =
             (C.TITLE + ' ' + C.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + C.SURNAME) 
  FROM CONTACT C
  INNER JOIN MEMBERSHIP M
    ON C.SERIALNUMBER=M.SERIALNUMBER
    WHERE M.MEMBERSHIPID=@MEMBERSHIPID;
  RETURN @name_to_return ;

END;
```

I call the function like this:

```
SELECT [dbo].[fnGetMemberNames](1)
```

But I only get one line of results.

```
Mrs      Jane        Doe
```

I should be seeing a carriage return OR comma delimited list with `Mr John Doe`

Comment: up votes for my very perfect question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetMemberNames] (@MEMBERSHIPID VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR(max)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @name_to_return AS VARCHAR(max);
  SET @name_to_return = NULL;
  SELECT  @name_to_return = ISNULL(@name_to_return,'') +
             (C.TITLE + ' ' + C.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + C.SURNAME) + Char(13) + Char(10) 
  FROM CONTACT C
  LEFT JOIN MEMBERSHIP M
    ON C.SERIALNUMBER=M.SERIALNUMBER
    WHERE M.MEMBERSHIPID=@MEMBERSHIPID;
  RETURN @name_to_return ;

END;
```

Comment: Thanks, is it supposed to show the carriage return in management studio? Because it comes up like a big space between the names...

Comment: Never mind, i just did "query results to text" and it comes up fine.. Thank you so much!!